# Java OpenGL rendering many triangles

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I have an openGL (JOGL actually, but same concepts apply here) app where I have a scene that renders approximately 10k triangles on each rendering pass. The scale and angle of the triangles must be computed on each rendering since the triangles need to stay at a constant size and rotation relative to the camera location.

I've tried using a display list and then scaling/rotating before each call to `glCallList`. That works, but it brings the system to a crawl. I've looking into using vertex buffers for this, but I'm not sure if this is the appropriate way to do it since I need to rotate/scale on each rendering.

Can someone help point me in the right direction for rendering this many triangles in each scene?

**EDIT** - This provides some additional context to the problem.

The application is a map application showing a 3d view of the world. There are certain shapes that need to be drawn on the surface pointing in a direction relative to a compass, i.e. at 30 degrees. The user can rotate the 3d view but the shapes must stay flat on the surface of the earth and also pointing the specified direction.

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: So the objects are: a) the same, and b) rotated relative to the compass, so they rotate in exactly the same way as the world when the user rotates the view (plus a bit of their own constant rotation)? Also, which version of OpenGL are you using?

Comment: They are the same objects, yes. The don't quite rotate the exact same way as the world because they need to rotate to be flat on the surface of the earth. I am using JOGL 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

Vertex Buffers with GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW and Indice Buffers with GL_STATIC_DRAW would be the best you could do in terms of simplicity.

If you have access to shaders (GLSL or HSL), use Vertex Buffers with GL_STATIC_DRAW and Indice Buffers with GL_STATIC_DRAW, and calculate the scale and rotation in the vertex shader. That way you could dump some of the work onto the GPU. (If the work was CPU heavy to begin with)

Maybe do some frustum culling before hand? Occlusion culling? The best way to speed up an application is to reduce the amount of triangles you are rendering.

Maybe even use some threading. One thread to render, the other to calculate the scale and angle.

Comment: thanks. Some simple frustum culling helped a lot when zoomed in when all points cannot be seen. I'm still having some trouble when all triangles are visible,but this is a good start for sure.

Comment: Culling would help for fill-rate problem or vertex/fragment processing power problem. 10k triangles is a tiny amount so this looks to me like a CPU problem - so Vertex Buffers are the way to go, to reduce the number of draw calls (to a single DrawArrays or DrawElements per frame). And avoid splitting threading and rendering into different threads, that's not a good way of thinking (the render calls are not expensive!). You can parallelize the computation itself if you need.

Comment: It looks like much of my time is taken up actually doing the computations for the rotations. I may need to figure out a way to reduce those.

Answer (score 1):

10.000 triangles is really not a big amount even for your average notebook GPU of today.

Display lists are kind of obsolete, that's not the most useful approach.

The first thing to do is **draw your trianges in a single draw call** - that should easily be possible.

So:

**1)** Keep all your triangle data (vertex coordinates) in a single `Buffer` (that's how JOGL handles vertex arrays it, IIRC). Then either:

- Update this buffer each frame on CPU and render all of it using `glVertexPointer` and `glDrawArrays`,
- Create a VBO and (`GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` type) and update it each frame with this buffer. A more modern approach, but not really a big difference from the above in terms of speed in this case.

And after that, you'd render all of that 10.000 triangles via a single `glDrawArrays` call.

This would still leave the calculation of triangles on the CPU, but would save you a lot of CPU time spent on driver calls - all of the triangles would be sent via your PCI-E at once and rendered in a blink.

If that's still too slow:

**2)** Think if you can/want to move some of the operations done on the triangles to the GPU and have the computations in the vertex shader. I cannot say too much here until I know what calculations you're doing, but I really hope that 1) would be enough.

If you had like 10.000 calls to `CallList` each frame, that's definitely the culprit of your low performance.

Comment: Currently all my triangles are drawn at (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), (-0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f), (0.5f, -1.0f, 0.0f), and then scale and rotated to the correct location. Because the user can zoom in and out and I need to maintain a constant size in pixels, the coordinates will change. How can I scale individual triangles differently when using glVertexPointer and glDrawArrays? Thanks.

Comment: OK, there are solutions, before I dive in here, can you please give a more detailed description (you can edit your question and add that) what your application actually does; what is your data and in which way it changes in time? It might be feasible to discuss the problem at a higher level.